# Action log of last ssh login

Tags: ssh, security, ubuntu-18.04

Assuming I give a sys admin temporary ssh (root/sudo) access to my server (Ubuntu 18.04) to assist with an issue, how would I check what changes were made by the person afterwards?

Some of the things I would like to know would include knowing which files were edited, which files were created, which files were opened, etc.

Is their an action log where one could check things like this?

Comment: Best thing you can do is to ask that person to keep a log.  If someone with root access wants to keep something hidden, nothing you can do about that.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille That's a tad bit disheartening from a security point of view tbh.

Comment: You would not allow someone to become root if you can't trust that person.  If you do, clearly, security is not one of your concerns.

Comment: @Gerald I'm talking about situations that involve both root or sudo access.

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned, there is a trust involved when someone has root access to your system.  I will make the assumption that the person is at least not hostile.

What I would do is to:

1. Ensure that you have a good, full backup of your system.  This is a good idea in general anyway.
2. Run a file integrity monitor tool such as [`aide`](https://aide.github.io/), and can tell you what file(s) changed.  This will include log files, the shell history file, and any other changes the person made (excepting hostile rootkit type changes which can be hidden).  You probably should copy the aide database off the system, just out of paranoia.
3. Let the person do the work.
4. Re-run aide and look at the list of changed files.  You can compare the current version with your backup to see what changes the person made.

`aide` is the most popular open source file integrity monitor.  Tutorials (e.g., [this one](https://blog.rapid7.com/2017/06/30/how-to-install-and-configure-aide-on-ubuntu-linux/)) and lots of [information](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FileIntegrityAIDE) about using it are available.  It has an Ubuntu package.  There are also commercial solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You could check shell's history, but shell history is easy to defeat. Even just prefacing a command with a space will keep it from being added to history, by default.

To go one step further, research enabling and using `pam_tty_audit` and shipping those audit logs off to a remote host for review. Commercial tools that do similar auditing would be things like [cmd.com](https://cmd.com/).

Comment: First time that I've heard of `pam_tty_audit` as well as `cmd.com`. Will most definitely read up about both of them. Can I get a gist of the difference between the two? And with regards to the login made by the sys admin earlier, so I guess I can't really get any info about his activity since from what I gather, their is no action log built-in right?

Comment: By default, bash logs history of commands that were run, but you can 1) Run commands without logging them, and 2) Delete bash history. It's imperfect, but it could be a start if you have enough trust in the person. So yes, there is an "action log" built in. As for the difference between `pam_tty_audit` and `cmd.com`, in broad terms, I'd think of `cmd.com` as `pam_tty_audit` with a pretty UI and easier to search. So, same thing, just more candy and chrome.